# Ballerina JMS connection pooling?

Tags: jms, connection-pooling, ballerina

I have a small Ballerina program where I receive a message from one JMS queue, call a stored procedure via JDBC and send a reply to another JMS queue.

The DB can process multiple requests in parallel, so I set up a JDBC connection pool for it. How do I set up a similar JMS connection pool?

Or should I just have a pool of Ballerina services instead?

Comment: Can you clarify the use-case here? It's common to need a JMS connection pool for larger application which establish lots of connections. However, if you have a "small" program it's not clear why you would necessarily need a JMS connection pool especially since sending JMS messages is already essentially asynchronous (i.e. you don't have to wait for the message to be processed before the call to `send` returns) unlike a DB request which does have to be processed before returning.

Comment: @JustinBertram The service is basically a stored procedure wrapper: it reads the input parameters from the request queue, calls the SP and writes the result to the response queue. I need to increase its throughput, and the DB server can process several requests in parallel. In Camel I would create a pooled JDBC connection factory and a pooled JMS connection factory for receiving multiple messages concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current ballerina implementation does not support any pooling of JMS resources.

The model of ballerina, however, should allow parallel processing, without explicit coding.

Using the code from the following GIST [jmsreceiver.bal](https://gist.github.com/JensWalter/d5b5f9435563a56a7a2c2e8be012c70e) the processing was done in parallel.

It produced the following log:

```
Initiating service(s) in 'receiver.bal'
2018-12-08 18:38:38,963 INFO  [ballerina/jms] - Message receiver created for queue MyQueue 
2018-12-08 18:38:57,445 INFO  [] - rcv ID:EMS-SERVER.55865C0BF16270:1500 
2018-12-08 18:38:58,461 INFO  [] - snd ID:EMS-SERVER.55865C0BF16270:1500 
2018-12-08 18:38:58,466 INFO  [] - rcv ID:EMS-SERVER.55865C0BF16270:1501 
2018-12-08 18:38:58,474 INFO  [] - rcv ID:EMS-SERVER.55865C0BF16271:1502 
2018-12-08 18:38:59,469 INFO  [] - snd ID:EMS-SERVER.55865C0BF16270:1501 
2018-12-08 18:38:59,472 INFO  [] - rcv ID:EMS-SERVER.55865C0BF16270:1503 
2018-12-08 18:38:59,478 INFO  [] - snd ID:EMS-SERVER.55865C0BF16271:1502
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with Ballerina, but reading through the [Ballerina JMS tutorial](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-guide/messaging-with-jms-queues/index.html) it appears Ballerina can use Java libraries. If that is the case, then you should check out https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms. It was forked from the mature ActiveMQ JMS Pool and enhanced to provide JMS 2.0 functionality. It is built on top of [Apache Commons Pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/), and it is generic (i.e. no ties to ActiveMQ) so it will work with any JMS implementation you choose.

[Here's a simple example](https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms/blob/master/pooled-jms-examples/src/main/java/org/messaginghub/jms/example/HelloWorld.java) of how to use it. You just need to instantiate a `JmsPoolConnectionFactory` and then call `setConnectionFactory` with the connection factory you would normall get from JNDI. After that you just use it like any normal JMS connection factory.

Comment: Since ballerina does not expose any means to directly access Java classes, the suggested pooling library would require reimplementing the ballerina JMS subsystem.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the clarification.